# Photo waterfall effect a la Tumblr Mosaic Viewer in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, photo-gallery, mosaic

This site just blew my mind:

http://tmv.proto.jp/#

I have a project where a similar effect would be fantastic. Is there a plugin to accomplish this effect in jQuery? The actual JS is at http://tmv.proto.jp/tmv.js

Million thanks!

-Æ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure you can use the [masonary](http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/) plugin and [infinite scroll](http://desandro.com/demo/masonry/docs/infinite-scroll.html) to get this same effect.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for, thank you! I might do this as a NextGEN Gallery plugin (WordPress), I'll post a link here for anyone finding this page via Google if I release any code.